# How to Use Roles field filter for AccountContactRelations in Visual flow?

Tags: visual-workflow, accountcontactrelation

We are looking to migrate to the new AccountContactRelations.
One process we need, is to query for a contact relationship with the account, where it's role is a specific value.

When running Visual Flow, there is no option of: "Contains".

The 'Roles' field, is a multipick list field on the new AccountContactRelations object.

[image]

How can I select the correct contact while running the flow? 
How can I get the contactid for a specific role?

Comment: Looking at the object definition, role is a single select picklist. Are you sure it's multi select?  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_accountcontactrole.htm

Comment: You are looking on the old object: AccountContactRole. I refer to the new object: AccountContactRelations. The new one is available in lightning as well. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_accountcontactrelation.htm

Comment: Sorry my bad, cant believe it's a standard field, I think it's the only standard msp in sfdc!  I think your only option is to query and loop through the responses, using a formula with the INCLUDES function, or to use invocable Apex.  W loops you would top out at ~1000 records that could be parsed, so depends on how much you can limit your query.

Comment: yea, the invokable apex was my approach. Just wanted to avoid apex.

Answer (score 0):

When you define multiple filters, the filter logic usually defaults to AND. However, if multiple filters have the same field selected and use the equals operator, the filters are combined with OR.

For example, your filters check whether a case’s Type equals Problem (1), Type equals Feature Request (2), and Escalated equals true (3). At runtime, those filters are combined to (1 OR 2) AND 3.

---

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=vpm_designer_elements_record_lookup.htm